# How do I change a table background color on click

Tags: javascript, html

I wonder if someone could help me please. I have a picture inside a small HTML table within a main table and I need the small table to change background color when I click on a thumbnail. I want to have three thumbnails with three different colors. 
Thanks a lot for your help. :)
Alina

Comment: Add some code to jsfiddle.net and it'll be easier for us to offer help.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst i was waiting for you to add some code i've created some sample code showing how to change the colour on click using jQuery:

http://jsfiddle.net/Grhcm/

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I have tried your code and I cant seem to make it work. I have put the code on jsfiddle.net/alina/XTssS/2/ I needed to have three thumbnails and when you click them they would change a single table's background color in turns.

Answer (score 0):

THis will do

$(document).function(){

```
$('table id ').click(function(){

$(this).css({background:'red'});

});

});
```